# Prepared statements in mysqli not working

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

Can someone explain to me why this isn't working. Trying to convert to prepared statements as per the advice of everybody but get stuck right at the beginning...the connection is fine and it returns no message, but there is no entry into my table (called nametable)

```
<?php
 $dbhost = "localhost";
 $dbuser = "root";
 $dbpass = "fidelio";
 $dbname = "test";
 $con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
 if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 die("Database connection failed: " . 
     mysqli_connect_error() . 
     " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")");
   }

$query = "INSERT INTO nametable (fname, lname) values (?,?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);
$firstName = "simon";
$lastName = "morris";
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"ss",$firstname, $lastname);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
$stmt->close();
?>
```

I added the last 2 lines and the error that comes back is

> Error: .

This works just fine but the prepared statements do not....anyone know why?

```
  $sql="INSERT INTO nametable (fname, lname)
  VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName')";
   if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)` to see if there's a related error message to help you?

Comment: Try `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die (mysqli_stmt_error($stmt))` to see the error.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "fidelio";
    $dbname = "test";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

     $firstName = "simon";
     $lastName = "morris";
          if ($stmtb = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO nametable (fname, lname) values (?,?)")) {
              $stmtb->bind_param('ss',$firstName, $lastName); 
              $stmtb->execute(); 
           }else {printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);}
```

Comment: hi echo, I tried that and it entered NULL and NULL into both fields. Bear in mind that the default is NULL. If I don't have a default, the error comes back as fname cannot be NULL. Very annoying...can't see why my or your code does not work...

Comment: because you are defining in your database that those columns not null by default or some them are primary key , the question is in your database. if you show your explain so we can see your table

Comment: Neither of them are primary keys. The values just aren't getting into the database for some reason that i cannot explain. The standard way of doing this works fine - the the edit above. Why is this....

Comment: you said that the default is NULL , and the error comes that fname cannot be NULL. did you make default value as null to fname also ?

Comment: no, please read what i have written again - if I do not set a default, then the error is that fname cannot be NULL. If set the default to NULL, the error simply comes back as Error:.

Comment: what error comes with my answer code , if there is default value null